# Transfer mail to other mail box

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I am working on an application where i need to transfer mails from a mailbox  to anoter one.I can not send these mails using smtp because this willchange the header information .I am using C# and out look api to process mails . is thre any way i can transfer  mails to other mail box without changing mail header.

---

By Transfer I mean, I need to take a mail from one mail box and move this to another mailbox without changing any header information. If I use smtp , header information will be changed. I have heared that using MAPI mail can be moved from one mail box to another mail box. any pointers.

Comment: Why can't you change the headers?

Comment: because before moving these mails,header info is being logged in a db which will be used to retrieve the mails later. The reason to move mail to other mail mailbox is that a process is running on that mail box which will put all the mails from mail box to a retention server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot load all relevant mailboxes into a single Outlook profile, then this cannot be solved using the Outlook API. It should however be possible to run a standalone application from an administrative account that accesses the Exchange information store directly via Extended MAPI. You can then open the source mailboxes sequentially and move the relevant mail items to the target mailbox.

This would allow you to run a batch job harvesting all mailboxes from a central location in a single giant operation. If however your task is to move messages as they appear then maybe addressing this in a more decentralized fashion via Outlook addins installed on the source machines might be a more sensible approach after all. Maybe if you told us a little bit more about your motivation for moving those items we can come up with an even better solution.

If you go for the centralized harvester approach I strongly recommend using a helper library like [Redemption](http://dimastr.com/redemption/) for this though as otherwise it will probably take a couple of months before you have gathered enough knowledge to address the task. The [RDO](http://dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/) framework (Redemption Data Objects) should be especially well suited to get you running ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to move the mails from one mail box to another using Redemption. This is like a copy mail from one mail box to another. First logon to the destination mail box using redemption.
Get the reference to the folder where you want to move the mail . In my case , it was inbox. now convert the outlook mail item to RDOMail and copy the rdomail to destination folder. here the is code -

```
 rdoSession.LogonExchangeMailbox("TEST", "ServerName");
 RDOExchangeMailboxStore mailBoxStore = (Redemption.RDOExchangeMailboxStore)
 rdoSession.Stores.DefaultStore;
 RDOFolder inboxFolder = null;

            foreach (RDOFolder rdoFolder in mailBoxStore.IPMRootFolder.Folders)
            {
                if (rdoFolder.Name.Equals("Inbox", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    inboxFolder = rdoFolder;
                    break;
                }
            }
            rdoMail.CopyTo(inboxFolder);
```

with this, mail will be copied to the new mail box without changing any header information.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Outloook API I'm sure there is support for backup and restore. So backup your mails from one account and restore it on the other. This would be my first try. PS: I'm not familiar with the API.

Answer (score 0):

What's the relationship of the mailboxes?  Are they on the same Exchange server?  If so, your best bet is to use MAPI to copy the messages.  If not, you can either export the messages to a PST or to a collection of .msg files.  Does this need to be automated?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "transfer"? If you're talking about the equivalent of drag and dropping a mail from one mailbox to another loaded inside the same Outlook profile, then just use the `MailItem.Move` method.

Answer (score 0):

Then what you need is MAPI.  It's a pretty complicated API.  There's one, long-out-of-print book about it, but that's it.  The best place to start is to download MFCMapi and look at how you might do what you need to, e.g. open two users' mailboxes and copy a message between them.  Then, look at the source for MFCMapi and see how it's done, and work from there.